# Activating a command after several sequential key presses?

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey

The main idea:

1. First key press activates the whole script, let it be Enter for example
2. If within 5 seconds after activation the particular keys are pressed and released in order, the main portion of the script is executed. If any other keys are pressed during this time, the script exits

I know how to set a timer, and how to check if a key is pressed or not at the current time (with GetKeyState), but I have no idea how to check if a key was pressed (and maybe released) during the specific time frame, until the timer runs out to be specific.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hotkey followed by hotstrings to capture the key sequence.

This doesn't exit the 5 second period of time early if other keys are pressed, but nothing would happen either.  If you wanted to exit immediately on detecting certain keystrokes you could go into a loop comparing A_LastKey to known 'ok' keys to press and exit early if something else is detected.

```
#Persistent    

hotstringsDisabled:=True

Return

; hotkey definition to enable hotstrings
Enter::
    hotstringsDisabled:=False
    SetTimer, DisableHotstrings, -5000  ; run once after 5 seconds
Return

DisableHotstrings:
    hotstringsDisabled:=True
Return

; hotstring definitions... 
; make as many as you like using this form...
; b0=don't backspace, c=case sensitive
:*b0c:custom::
    If hotstringsDisabled
        Return

    ;your code to do something useful goes here...
    Msgbox % "A_ThisHotkey=" A_ThisHotkey "`n" "A_LastKey=" A_LastKey
Return
```

The initial hotkey could also be combined (just depends on how you want to do it)...

```
Enter::
    hotstringsDisabled:=False
    Sleep 5000
    hotstringsDisabled:=True
Return
```

The `Sleep 5000` statement is what you would replace with a loop if you wanted to exit early on some other keys or something like that.

Comment: Also, in case it is not self-evident to you from the code above, you would hit `Enter` and then type the sequence `custom` in order to make something happen